# How to close RMI-Server without getting UnmarshallException?

Tags: rmi

i programmed an RMI-Example and now the problem with my Program is, i'm trying to terminate or close the Server if the User puts in `"closeBookManager()"`. Consider following Code :

```
if(in.equals("closeBookManager()")) {
    service.closeBookManager();
    break;
}
```

This piece of code is within a while loop, which is always true, until the user types in `"closeBookManager()"`

Now the problem is if the user types in that mentioned string, i would like to close the Server. I tried it with `System.exit(0)` on the Server Side

```
public void closeBookManager() throws RemoteException {
    ...
    System.exit(0);
}
```

but it throws this Error on the Client Side :

---

> Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error
>   unmarshaling return header; nested exception is: 
>     java.io.EOFException    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:229)
>     at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:162)    at
>   java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:227)
>     at
>   java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:179)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.closeBookManager(Unknown Source)   at
>   Client.main(Client.java:66) Caused by: java.io.EOFException   at
>   java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:267)    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:215)
>     ... 5 more

---

I also tried to unbind and unexport the Object but it wont work.

Please tell me what am i doing wrong or what could i do.
I will appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0):

Have it exit in a separate thread after a short delay to allow time for the remote method to complete and send its result back.